# Any way can implement the function as picture shows

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image

[image]

As you see, a image cycle show area. is it in the first cell of table or some other ways implement?

Comment: does it scroll with the rest of the table cells ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it scroll with the content or is it static?

**If it scrolls with the content:**
Using `tableHeaderView` is the easiest solution.

**If it is static:**
Just layout as a separate view above the `UITableView` in Interface Builder or code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small pagecontrol with scrollView and add that to tableHeaderView and then you can achieve the functionality shown in picture.